# Counting how many items arrive the next day over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a problem. I want to calculate how many items arrived the next day for the customer. This means for example I have the customer with the `customerId == 1` and I want to look at the day `2022-05-04` to see how many parcels arrived the next day. The next day would be `2022-05-05`. If we add the two days together for the customer, we get 2.
The last date should not have a value, for example `2022-05-08 == None`.

I have tried to calculate the next date. But how can I count and calculate how many items arrived on the next day?

Dataframe:

```py
   customerId    fromDate
0           1  2022-05-04
1           1  2022-05-05
2           1  2022-05-05
3           1  2022-05-06
4           1  2022-05-08
5           2  2022-05-10
6           2  2022-05-12
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

d = {'customerId': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     'fromDate': ['2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-10', '2022-05-12']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def nearest(items, pivot):
  try:
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
  except:
    return None

df['fromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fromDate'], errors='coerce').dt.date
df["count_next_date"] = df['fromDate'].apply(lambda x: nearest(df['fromDate'], x)) 

[OUT]
   customerId    fromDate  count_next
0           1  2022-05-04  2022-05-04
1           1  2022-05-05  2022-05-05
2           1  2022-05-05  2022-05-05
3           1  2022-05-07  2022-05-07
4           2  2022-05-10  2022-05-10
5           2  2022-05-12  2022-05-12
```

What I want:

```py
   customerId    fromDate  count_next
0           1  2022-05-04  2
1           1  2022-05-05  1
2           1  2022-05-05  1
3           1  2022-05-06  0
4           1  2022-05-08  None
5           2  2022-05-10  0
6           2  2022-05-12  None
```

Comment: Trying to understand: 2022-05-08 has the value of none, becaue no items will be arriving the next day - 2022-05-09. If that's the case, why 2022-05-06 has the value None?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. `2022-05-08` is `None` because there is no information on whether an item will arrive tomorrow or not. For this reason it is `None`. `2022-05-06` is `0` because nothing arrived on `2022-05-07` or we have no value for it and therefore we think as if nothing arrived. The last data point or date should therefore always be `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Annotated code

```
# Convert the column to datetime
df['fromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fromDate'])

# Group by custid and prev date to calculate 
# number of items arriving next day
date = df['fromDate'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
items = df.groupby(['customerId', date], as_index=False).size()

# Merge the item count with original df 
out = df.merge(items, how='left')

# Fill the nan values with 0
out['size'] = out['size'].fillna(0)

# mask the item count corresponding to last date for each customerid
out['size'] = out['size'].mask(~out['customerId'].duplicated(keep='last'))
```

##### Result

```
print(out)

   customerId   fromDate  size
0           1 2022-05-04   2.0
1           1 2022-05-05   1.0
2           1 2022-05-05   1.0
3           1 2022-05-06   0.0
4           1 2022-05-08   NaN
5           2 2022-05-10   0.0
6           2 2022-05-12   NaN
```